# Change People "Reached" to Impressions

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, people-reached

Over at Open Source.SE, it's easy to figure out how many people would've seen a post, since it's still in private beta. With 313 users, you wouldn't expect to have reached more than that amount. Yet:

[image: Profile Amount of Users Reached]

I've reached 778 people. Clearly not.

***So here's the request:***

Let's change "people reached" to "impressions". This is much more accurate, and is already used in many analytical applications, such as YouTube. And who doesn't like impressing people?

So, instead of having "reached" 778 people, I would have 778 impressions. Sounds great! Right?

Comment: Remember that each user post counts, that means that if the same user saw two of your posts it would count *twice* for the people reacher stat.

Comment: @Braiam That's exactly why we should change it to impressions, instead of keeping it like this

Answer (score 11):

No, not really.

Who said the people reaching the post were impressed by it? For all we know, it might be the opposite. Since we can't read the viewers' mind, safest thing is to use "reached" since that's a fact. What they did with the post, we can't possibly know.

Comment: The statistics used were from a private beta

Comment: @Zizouz212 fair enough, so this is weird but out of scope here, removed from answer - you might start a new bug report for this.

Comment: _Impressions_ doesn't mean someone was impressed; it's a pretty standard term in web analytics, meaning the number of times something was displayed on a user's screen.

Comment: @1999 well, I didn't know that so guess most people seeing this stat won't know it either, as it's not part of a web analytics report.

Comment: Lots of web-savvy users know what an impression is...